# Jquery Sidebar/Panel Close Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sidebar

I Create one Sidebar/Panel, You can view demo **[Here (JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/W7sNp/4/)**

Issue is that on Side-panel whenever I click, It Close. My need is Side-panel close only when we click on box which we use to open side panel.

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="dock">
            <li id="files">
                <ul class="free">
                    <li class="header"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dock"><IMG SRC="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/pin-128.png" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0" ALT="Dock"  style = "padding-top: 12px;"></a><a href="#" class="undock"><IMG SRC="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/oxygen/48x48/actions/note2.png" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0" ALT=""  style = "padding-top: 12px;"></a><H5 ID="colorgreen">DISCOVER </h4></li>
                    <div id="accordion">
                      <h3>Section 1</h3>
                      <div class = "accordionheight">
                        <p>
                        accordion 1 content
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <h3>Section 2</h3>
                      <div class = "accordionheight">
                        <p>
                        accordion 2 content
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <h3>Section 3</h3>
                      <div class = "accordionheight">
                        <p>
                        accordion 3 content
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="tools">
                <ul class="free">
                    <li class="header"><a href="#" class="dock"><IMG SRC="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/pin-128.png" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0" ALT="Dock"></a><a href="#" class="undock"><IMG SRC="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/oxygen/48x48/actions/note2.png" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0" ALT="Undock"></a><H5 ID="colorgreen">FACT FILE</H5></li>
                    <li><a href="#">This is one item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">This is one item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">This is one item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">This is one item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">This is one item</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var docked = 0;

    $("#dock li ul").height($(window).height());


    $("#dock li").click(function () {
        var test = $(this).find("ul").css('width');
        if (test == "0px") {
            $(".docked").addClass("free").removeClass("docked").animate({
                right: "-40px",
                width: '0px'
            }, 200);
            $(this).find("ul").addClass("docked").removeClass("free").animate({
                right: "40px",
                width: '180px'
            }, 200);

        } else {
            $(this).find("ul").addClass("free").removeClass("docked").animate({
                right: "-40px",
                width: '0px'
            }, 200);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that, because your panels (`ul.free`) are inside the `li#files`/`li#tools`, these elements also receive a click event, when your panels are clicked (because the click event goes up to all parents until `stopPropagation()` is called).

You can work around this, by simply adding an additional element in the sidebar list items like this:

```html
<ul id="dock">
    <li id="files">
        <div class="handler"></div>
        <ul class="free">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li id="tools">
        <div class="handler"></div>
        <ul class="free">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Than bind the click event to this handler div:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dock .handle").click(function(){
        var test = $(this).next("ul").css('width');
        if (test=="0px") {
            $(".docked").addClass("free")
                .removeClass("docked")
                .animate({right:"-40px",width:'0px'}, 200);
            $(this).next("ul").addClass("docked")
                .removeClass("free")
                .animate({right:"40px",width:'180px'}, 200);
        } else {
            $(this).next("ul").addClass("free")
                .removeClass("docked")
                .animate({right:"-40px",width:'0px'}, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

I also updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7sNp/5/).

Comment: Yes, It is.
What I want. Thank you Jan

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

> The nested ul which is inside #files li will also respond to the click
>   in your code. But we can prevent that by using stopPropagate() which
>   will prevent the handler to be associated with the parent elements.

**Jquery**

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var docked = 0;

                $("#dock li ul").height($(window).height());


                $("#dock li").click(function(event){
                        var test = $(this).find("ul").css('width');

                    if (test=="0px"){
$(".docked").addClass("free").removeClass("docked").animate({right:"-40px",width:'0px'}, 200);                      $(this).find("ul").addClass("docked").removeClass("free").animate({right:"40px",width:'180px'}, 200);

                    }else{
                        $(this).find("ul").addClass("free").removeClass("docked").animate({right:"-40px",width:'0px'}, 200);
                    }

                    });
                                $("#dock li ul").click(function(event)
                                                       {
                                                           event.stopPropagation();
                                                       });
                });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll appreciate your help,
But above answer solve my problem :)
You can Help by adding close button on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W7sNp/5/